# 'Bundler.require' requiring all gems?

Tags: ruby, bundler

Trying to figure out Ruby's Bundler library. My understanding is we can require only certain groups, but my setup seems to be loading gems specified in other groups as well.

**Gemfile**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

# Specify your gem's dependencies in apple.gemspec
gemspec

group :production do
  gem 'mail'
  gem 'bundler'
  gem 'pry'
  gem 'commander'
  gem 'fastlane'
  gem 'spaceship'
  gem 'highline'
  gem 'terminal-table'
  gem 'clipboard'
  gem 'date'
  gem 'mysql2'
  gem 'fileutils'
  gem 'redis'
  gem 'json'
  gem 'logger'
  gem 'jira-ruby', :require => 'jira-ruby'
end

group :jenkins do
  gem 'terminal-table'
  gem 'pry'
  gem 'mail'
  gem 'jira-ruby'
  gem 'spaceship'
end
```

**test.rb**

```
require 'pry'
binding.pry
require 'rubygems'
require 'bundler/setup'
Bundler.require(:jenkins) # I want this step to require only gems listed under 'jenkins' group in `Gemfile`. 

...
```

When I run the code, it seems `Bundler.require(:jenkins)` step seems to be requiring all gems specified in Gemfile,

[image]

I am still in the process of understanding Bundler, pardon me if the question I asked is too obvious. Does anyone know how to only load the gems from bundler groups? Thanks in advance!!

Comment: What makes you think it requires gems not specified in group `jenkins`?

Comment: @idmean Thanks for reply! From the screenshot, Bundler seems to be loading all gems I specified in `Gemfile` (even the one's from `production` group, which I don't want). Do you know how to load only gems from `jenkins` group, please?

Comment: Bump! Anyone? :D

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of confusing, but as far as I can tell from using it myself, it only requires the gems in the given group even though it lists all of them.

It's pretty easy to see this for yourself, just try using one from the production group

```
Bundler.require(:jenkins)
Date.new # Should error
```

Really it seems like you may have noticed this yourself, but you just didn't realize.. If it was including all of them you wouldn't have needed to require pry in test.rb :)